# Call method from class in class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have no clue how to write a title correctly but what I mean is to make something like this:

```
public static MusicPlayer _Player = new MusicPlayer();

_Player.Play.Song(TestPath);
```

where MusicPlayer is a class and in that class I want to make something like property or another class I don't know how to call it, which will have two methods. My code for now:

```
public class MusicPlayer
{
    //Variables, Methods and Properties in MusicPlayer
    //And then Play which can have two tipes of play.
    public static class Play
    {
        //This one should be called if I want to play one song
        public static void Song(String _path)[...]

        //And this one when I want to play from list, defined in MusicPlayer class
        public static void List()[...]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just create a public static readonly property `Play` in the class

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that you need your `MusicPlayer` methods/inner classes to be `static`. You are creating an instance of `MusicPlayer` with the line ending `new MusicPlayer();`. You'll have access to instance variables of `MusicPlayer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
public class MusicPlayer
{
    public class Player
    {
        public static void Song(String _path)[...]
        public static void List()[...]
    }

    private Player m_player = new Player();

    public Player Play
    {
        get { return m_player; }
    }
}
```

This defines a `Player` class in `MusicPlayer`. Also it creates a member variable of type `Player` and a property that allows you to access the `Player` instance from the outside *using an instance of `MusicPlayer`*:

```
var mplayer = new MusicPlayer();
mplayer.Play.Song(...);
```

If you do not want to create an instance of `MusicPlayer`, you could also make this static:

```
public class MusicPlayer
{
    public class Player
    {
        public static void Song(String _path)[...]
        public static void List()[...]
    }

    private static Player m_player = new Player();

    public static Player Play
    {
        get { return m_player; }
    }
}
```

You can now use `MusicPlayer.Play.Song(...)` without having to create an instance.

Comment: The first one doesn't make me call Song and List methods. Second one instead doesn't let me call Play Prop at all.

Comment: Yes, because you need an instance of the `MusicPlayer` class. Try `var mplayer = new MusicPlayer(); mplayer.Play.Song(...);`.

Comment: Already did. Take a look in my question. I made `public static MusicPlayer _Player = new MusicPlayer();

_Player.Play.Song(TestPath);`

Comment: Ok I did it. Removed `static` from methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
public class MusicPlayer
{
    public MusicPlayer()
    {
        Play = new Play();
    }
    public Play Play { get; private set; }

}

public class Play
{
    //This one should be called if I want to play one song
    public void Song(String _path){}

    //And this one when I want to play from list, defined in MusicPlayer class
    public void List() { }
}
```

And then using like

```
new MusicPlayer().Play.Song("");
```